# How to install MacTeX 2015 successfully in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, latex

I upgraded to El Capitan in my new Macbook Air. El Capitan does not allow to use `/usr/texbin/` for storage so LaTeX community had to move their files to `/Library/TeX`. 
MacTeX 2015 is not fully compatible with El Capitan. 
There is at least some path reconfigurations which has to be done in individual programs described in the [guide](https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf). 
However, I have not succeeded in getting MacTeX fully working in El Capitan.

### Fixing LaTeX in El Capitan

All stages went right but not the following with TeX Live Utility. 
I am doing the step in the guide [MacTEX-2015 and El Capitan](https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf) (page 3)

> For previous versions of TEX Live Utility open TEX Live
>   Utility→Preferences and click on the Choose. . . button as in Figure
>   (4). That opens a file chooser. Type Shift-Cmd-G, enter /Library/TeX
>   into the dialog box as shown in Figure (5) and then press Return.
>   Finally DoubleClick on texbin.

I get

[image]

### After Unsuccessful Setup-2015.pkg

I run `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.mactlmgr.tlu.plist` to delete the changes made by the applicaiton *Setup-2015.pkg* proposed by hakaze, because of infinity loop when starting Tex-live with those changes. 
I found the `Library/TeX/texbin` eventually.

---

How can you set up MacTeX 2015 successfully in El Capitan?

Comment: You probably should run the 'Setup-2015' app (within the Applications/TeX folder) which fixes paths and permissions for the MacTeX installation and GUI programs under El Capitan. This fixed my issues with TeXLiveUtility amongst other things.

Comment: Which path is defined for TeX programs in Tex Live Utility -> Preferences?

Comment: @patrix /Library/TeX/ described in the guide but giving the error (picture in the body).

Comment: @hakaze Can you please give an exact path for `Setup-2015`. I do not find such an application in /Library/TeX/.

Comment: @Masi The setup package is part of the normal MacTeX installation and should be found here: `/Applications/TeX/Setup-2015.pkg`

Comment: @hakaze I run the application but now when I start texlive it stays in the infinite loop. Do you know how you can remove changes made by the setup tool? I would like to test patrix's method.

Comment: @Masi You can try to delete TLU's preferences (its default will be re-created at start-up): `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.mactlmgr.tlu.plist`

Comment: You are looking at two different folders here. The second screenshot is showing `/Applications/TeX`, the Terminal output is from `/Library/TeX`. No need to enable hidden files/folders here, I would be more concerned if both would be the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the guide when defining the path for TeX programs in TeX Live Utility.

- In TeX Live Utility, open Preferences
- Click on "Choose"
- Do *one* of the following

  - press <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd>, type `/Libary/TeX`, click on "Go", double-click on `texbin` and then click on "Choose"
  - press <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd>, type `/Libary/TeX/texbin`, click on "Go" and then click on "Choose"

Comment: I updated the body of the question. I see no `/Library/TeX/texbin` in the system. I installed MacTeX 2015 by clicking everything. Apparently, something went wrong there. What do you think?

Comment: Based on the screenshot in the question, you are looking for `texbin` in `/Applications/TeX`, not in `/Library/TeX`. Maybe run `ls -al /Library/TeX` and add output to the question.

Comment: @masi So `texbin` is where it should be :-) Can you setup TeX Live Utility now as well?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and patience! Now, the Finder search also works for .tex files. It was a complication of unsuccessful MacTeX 2015 installation in El Capitan.